# Is swastika really treated as offensive even when it's used for religious purposes in profile pictures or chat?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, profile-picture, policy

I have heard many controversies regarding the use of a swastika in the Stack Exchange network. But all the cases I noticed were clearly using a Nazi swastika. To make it clear, swastikas are of different kinds:

### Hindu swastika

[image: Hindu swastika]

### Jain Prateek Chihna (Jainism Symbol)

[image: Jain Prateek Chihna (Jainism Symbol)]

### The Hachisuka swastika (a family crest used by the Japanese Hachisuka clan).

[image: The Hachisuka swastika]

Many many such examples exist for the use of a swastika which existed long before the Nazis.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swastika)

> The swastika (also known as the gammadion cross, cross cramponnée, or tetraskelion) (as a character: 卐 or 卍) is an ancient religious symbol that generally takes the form of an equilateral cross, with its four legs bent at 90 degrees. It is considered to be a sacred and auspicious symbol in Hinduism, Buddhism, and Jainism and dates back to before the 2nd century B.C.

And here are the Nazi swastikas:

[image: Nazi swastika]

[image: Nazi swastika]

Which are clearly distinguishable. So do we allow the non-tilting religious swastika symbol in profile picture and chat? If not, then why? If they are so easy to distinguish from the Nazi swastika.

Even the SE network has two religious sites ([Hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/) and [Buddhism](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/)) which have symbolic significance of the swastika symbol. And maybe a third one ([Jainism](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/98257/jainism)) can be live in the future.

Comment: Similar enough. I can understand those flagging as offensive posts with such images, or asking moderators to reset such avatars. Note that many trolls use them on purpose to offend, thinking that "hey, but it's an innocent swastika!" will be enough to justify their trolling.

Comment: @ShadowWizard My point is, it's quite easy to distinguish, so why not just get offended when it have bad intention only.

Comment: The impact of such evil is big. Huge. Can't be measured. True, the swastika is yet another victim, innocent as the rest, but still... I'm afraid it will remain an offensive symbol for many years to come, for millions of people. I'm not one of them (i.e. won't flag myself and not getting offended), but can understand those who are.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I praise you for your view on this but I'm very much in favor to put those images in a spoiler markup `>!`

Comment: @ShadowWizard - I've had at least one person claim that they were using the swastika for religious purposes, then I've gone to their "about me" and found a screed praising Hitler. So yeah, trolls have tried to hide behind the religious argument, which further poisons this for other people.

Comment: @rene on this, I'm afraid I disagree. I used to think this way too, until reading [this answer by Robert](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/a/19073/46868). What can I say, he's a convincing person! :)

Comment: Maybe a compromise could be to be a bit more lenient with the non-nazi symbols on sites like [buddhism.se] and [hinduism.se], where the connection should be clearer to the userbase, but more strict in its use on other sites? I guess there a big difference between wearing such symbolism on [hinduism.se] or [judaism.se]. As you can see, the general community is not really comfortable with it, so maybe a per-site comprise would be sufficient, seeing that you seem to be especially concered about sites for Buddhism and Hinduism existing on SE.

Answer (score 38):

When you say "fag" - some folks going back more than a couple of generations will wonder if you're referring to a cigarette. *Colloquially*, however, most people will interpret the word as a pejorative allusion to a gay person, usually a man. I don't say "fag" even though it has a prior meaning because I don't want to hurt people's feelings, and I hate the connotation that the word now carries. Heck, even *gay* once carried a different meaning.

That's what matters here - the *colloquial* reaction that a word or an image is likely to bring out in folks, and how that feeling influences the experience that they have on our sites.

The Nazis ruined it, for everyone, at least for the foreseeable future. They took lots of things from lots of people, including a once benign and innocuous symbol, and then tainted it much like radiation still taints the grounds at Chernobyl. I don't know if the stigma surrounding the symbol has a half-life.

What we must consider is that *most* people will see a swastika and immediately associate it with the Nazis and all of the horrible things that they did. Because of them, and that, we simply can't take a chance on allowing it.

Comment: Almost 1000 years ago, Jews and Muslims were slaughtered in the crusades, under the banner of the Jerusalem Cross. http://imgur.com/fYSbFrH One could argue that the Christian cross is similar enough to that of the Crusades. Would you say the same for the cross as you do for the swastica, and, either way, why?

Comment: @Tim: I suspect for most people it's a question of ratios of good associations to bad. The Christian cross, in the West, has an enormous weight of positive associations, so the crimes committed under it or its variants don't taint it too much. But, again in the West, there's far more familiarity with Nazi propaganda than Hinduism, Jainism, or obscure Japanese heraldry. So, in a practical sense, it's a question of common associations. Perhaps if there was some continuity of well-known Nazi organization that *used* the swastika but *condemned* Hitler's Germany things would be different.

Comment: No, the Christian cross is not generally met with a colloquial reaction similar to that to the swastika and trying to make the argument is really silly. Probably not even back then - except among those unfortunate enough to be, uh, liberated by the Crusaders, I guess

Comment: To be fair, if you say "fag" in the UK more people will think you're talking about a cigarette than a homosexual.  Though, as ever, context is important.

Comment: @TimPost Fag is a different thing, because faq word was not associated with any good thing either, it was never the word of believe or faith or anything positive. On the contrary swastika have too much positive associated with it. 2 of the top 4 major religion have it's significance and they are not some small community either.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Hinduisms and Buddhism are not that small religion as ypu supposed. If we even ignore Jainism or some Japaneses community and many such small sects, tribe, religions. Still it have significance for 2 out of 4 top religious groups.

Comment: @AnkitSharma: I'm talking about the West, where yes, many people go their whole lives without knowing even all the major symbols of Hinduism (or Buddhism), never mind the minor ones. (Quick! What does the dove symbolize in Christianity?) But anyone in the West over the age of 10 who does not know about Nazi Germany and their flag is living in denial.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I always considered StackExchange a global site not a western site. We have sites of different religion, topics and interests and now sticking to western believes and enforcing them doesn't looks like a global acceptance.

Comment: @AnkitSharma: Yessss, but. The devs are mostly native English speakers. The company is basically American with some adjuncts. The little injokes in badges and hats and so forth are almost all American. And in practice, if something can reasonably offend a sizeable chunk of the userbase *and* most of the staff... well, you can imagine.

Comment: @Tim well, it did happen 1000 years ago. Those things **do** have expiry date, and pretty sure 1000 years from now,  the swastika  symbol will be "clear" again.

Comment: @NathanTuggy That doesn't sound fair to me, not after we have siet dedicated to this religions

Comment: @AnkitSharma: Who said it was fair? Having to avoid something perfectly innocent because someone else might take the wrong meaning from it is never especially fair.

Comment: @AnkitSharma I'm sure that on  a SE site specifically about a religion that uses the symbol, you are free to use the symbol as is appropriate within the site's and the religion's context.

Comment: Five years later, I wonder if your answer might change? Especially your interpretation of "most people" as the internet continues to erase borders.

Comment: @LShaver That's the point exactly - the term "_most_ people" will always be dynamic and should be calculated on the fly, and that's why it's important to think about who that really encompasses when contemplating what's likely to be offensive. But I'm not seeing borders eroding that might lead to swastikas not provoking a visceral negative reaction in a great many people.

Comment: @LShaver it wouldn't have much value if his answer would change, as he no longer is employed by SE.

Comment: @TimPost I agree about "a great many people", or even "most people in Europe and North America". With your phrase "the Nazis ruined it," you allude to how a cultural symbol, important to millions in Asia, now has a negative connotation to millions outside of Asia. While I agree that the swastika should continue to be banned in most situations, I think that recent history has taught us the importance of being more sensitive to how this stance may be difficult for people without a western cultural background.

Comment: @LShaver I agree with you. I was literally _living in Asia_ and had been for a decade when I wrote it - I've had to get extra pages put into two passports, and I can tell you, the symbol is loathed nearly everywhere that I've been. But, I agree with your assessment that I should have tried to find a way to promote individuality more.  I would support making allowances for the non-nazi Swastika _provided that rules lawyers weren't using it as a substitute way to harass people, by using an allowed swastika as a clear prop for the Nazi one_.

Answer (score 12):

This is indeed a very delicate subject, and there is no clear cut yes or no.

I think we have to consider a few things: we don't want people to feel deeply offended by something they see. The Nazi swastika is something that deeply offends most users, and therefore is clearly something we shouldn't allow.

The other swastikas are a little difficult: some users can still feel offended, but that is often due to their lack of understanding the swastika actually means something else than they associate it with. I don't feel offended by the non-Nazi swastikas, but if someone does, I, as a user, would remove it. That fits in the *be nice* policy. As a site I don't think we should disallow the use of non-Nazi swastikas, just because they look like the other one.

Answer (score 6):

The Nazi Swastika was actually based off these other symbols, so of course it's hard to differentiate.

I'd personally love to see the symbol returned to its original meaning, but I doubt that will happen anytime soon.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strafgesetzbuch_section_86a), German law bans the symbol:

> The Swastika as a symbol of the Nazi Party, prohibited in all variants, including mirrored, inverted etc.

The Nazis even used the symbol on its side, instead of diagonally:

> [image: Two red Nazi swastika flags]
>  Because their list of awful crimes wasn't going to be long enough, they had to steal a religious symbol and then completely ruin it. In case you needed another reason to hate Nazis...

I don't particularly like having the image in profile pictures because it is very easy to apply it to your account in other communities. This runs the risk of having it taken offensively.

I do think that it is acceptable to have in the "about me" section as long as there's an explanation of what the picture means. As long as the explanation is not "because Nazis" of course.

While I can't determine what's acceptable on those specific religious sites, I think that we need to consider the effects that the symbol has on other sites, especially those with broader global audiences. I don't want anyone getting in trouble, especially legally, over these pictures. (I'm not sure how the laws work exactly, but I think it's best we be careful.)

Comment: Note that the symbols that are liable to prosecution in Germany include symbols which are so similar as to be mistaken for those named in the Criminal Code. It already suffices to present an image which at a distance of some metres conveys passers-by the impression that it is a swastika. This also applies to slightly modified symbols and insignia which are so similar as to be mistaken for those belonging to the former National Socialist organisations.[[source](https://www.verfassungsschutz.de/download/publication-2015-04-right-wing-extremism-signs-symbols-and-banned-organisations.pdf)]

Comment: sidenote: presentation in educational, documentary or similarly innocuous context is exempt from that rule.

Comment: So, if somebody in Germany surfs to this page, is he breaking the law?  (I'm not entirely serious, but partly.)

Answer (score 6):

Years ago, in college, I was at lunch with a couple friends, who before that never met each other. She looked askance at his swastika ring. I asked him "are you Buddhist?" Me knowing it as a non-Nazi symbol as well, but as a way to broach the subject. She was relieved he said yes, that's his Buddhist wedding ring.

A lot of people don't know the alternate origins and meanings. If the only meaning you have is from Nazi Germany, then they will associate you with Nazism. There has been no great push to reclaim the symbol, so in many people's minds it will be Nazi only for a long long time.